# Setting up WMS in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: wms, arcgis-online, stream

I am looking for a method to export data (Feature Layers) from my Company's ArcGIS Online account.  I see that there is a option to export data in various formats in the Gallery section, but we want to make this export as seamless as possible.  The objective is to input this data into Pointerra to view GIS data that is stored in ArcGIS Online.

How can I make my ArcGIS Online data available via WMS so a software like Pointerra can read my data?

Pointerra can also stream in TMS, WMTS, ESI REST Services (Not primary option).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your user account is set up with 'Creator' user type and 'Publisher' or 'Administrator' role. Go to the item details page of your hosted feature layer. You should see a list of options on the right hand side. Select 'Publish' and choose WFS (Web Feature Service) from the drop down menu. This is an OGC compliant format that is very similar to a WMS.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But my endpoint (Pointerra) does not have a direct support connection for WFS Service.

Comment: I don't believe you can publish WMS layers from ArcGIS Online. You would need [ArcGIS Enterprise](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/wms-services.htm) and you can follow this [tutorial](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/tutorial-publishing-a-wms-service.htm).

Comment: @theMoreYouNgo Did you end up finding a solution for publishing a WMS?